# Mocking dependencies inside of an AOP object using Testbox and AOP/1

Tags: unit-testing, coldfusion, aop, lucee

I am curious if there is an easier way to mock the dependencies inside a component that uses AOP.

For example I have a component that uses CRUD methods to persist changes to the database. For audit logging I figured I could use AOP so I didn't have to put my logging calls inside of the methods. The issue that I am running into is during unit testing when I want to mock the database and session storage used inside the object that provides the AOP. The only way I have been able to figure out how to fake the database and session is to create a new mock component file that extends the original and then overrides the init method. Using this method is not very flexible as I have to create several extra files for a simple unit test. Below is some of the test code:

This is the bean that gets created with the di/1 bean factory:

```
//customerBean.cfc
component accessors="true" extends="models.abstracts.AbstractModel" displayname="Customer" {
    property name="ID"  type="numeric" default="0";
    property name="Name" type="string" length="100" default="<Unknown>" logEvents="update";
    property name="Type" type="string" default="Homeowner" logEvents="update";
    property name="Status" type="string" default="Active" logEvents="update";

    public any function init(customerDAO) {
        variables.DAO = arguments.customerDAO;
    }

}
```

Here is the component that the customerBean extends:

```
//abstractModel.cfc
component accessors="true" {

    public any function doCreate(required struct data) {
        setID(save());
        return getID();
    }
}
```

This is the AOP component that has two dependencies that need to be mocked:

```
//customerLogger.cfc
component accessors="true" {
    property name="tableToLogTo" default="CustomerLogs" setter="false";

    public any function init(LoggerServiceDAO, scopeStorage) {
        variables.loggerServiceDAO = arguments.loggerServiceDAO;
        variables.scopeStorage = arguments.scopeStorage;
    }


    public any function after(targetBean, methodName, args, result) {
        variables.loggerServiceDAO.insertLog(method=arguments.methodName, user=variables.scopeStorage.get('session.user.id'));
    }
}
```

Here is the code I use to get the CustomerBean:

```
bf = new framework.aop(
    folders="/models,/system,/tests/Mocks", config={transients=["entity", "process", "transients", "report", "forms"],transientPattern="Bean$"}
);
bf.intercept('CustomerBean', 'CustomerLoggerMock', 'doCreate');
customerBean = bf.getBean('CustomerBean', {customerDAO: customerDAOMock});
```

Ideally what I would like to do is use Testbox to mock the two objects and use the nice built in verification methods. Is this possible or am I stuck creating all of these mock files?